# Scaling for Wishart distribution

Tags: covariance-matrix, wishart-distribution

If $X$ has a Wishart distribution $W_p(n,\Sigma)$ , what's the distribution for $cX$ where $c>0$ ?

I know that for a $\chi^2_n (x)$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, $c\chi^2 $ follows $\Gamma(x;\frac{n}{2},2c)$ for the scaling property of gamma distribution so the answer should not be so obvious.

This question arose because $\frac{1}{n} W$ should be the the correct distribution for the sample covariance, according to what I understand from theory.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found an answer but I leave open the question for the sake of the community:

Actually using the theorem found here [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) :[image]
$$CXC^t \sim W(n,C\Sigma C^t)
$$
and taking $C$ as the diagonal matrix :
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
   \sqrt{c} & \ldots  & 0  \\
   \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
   0 & \cdots  & \sqrt{c}  \\
\end{matrix} \right) 
$$

Ergo in this case $cX$ should be $W(n,c\Sigma)$ distributed.  Relating to my example for the sample covariance, $C = \text{diag}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$. Hence, $\frac{1}{n}X=\hat{\Sigma}$ should be simply $W(n, \frac{1}{n}\Sigma) $ distributed.

Comment: You've changed your notation in midstream from $c$ to $n$, it appears.  You asked about $cX$, but you are responding with $1/n$... and since $\Sigma$ is a parameter, it doesn't have a distribution (referring to your last sentence.)

Comment: Yes , i know. The question arose for the purpose of covariance sample matrix distrubution, where I have $ c=\frac{1}{n} $ . It's a dummy scalar variable. Of course in this case $X=n\hat{\Sigma}$ has a distribution. I edited the last $\Sigma$ with an hat.